# Construct this matrix based on two vectors MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I do have 2 vectors and i want to construct a matrix based onr and c

r =

```
 1
 2
 4
 6
 8
```

c =

```
 2
 4
 6
 8
10
```

i want to construct a matrix A such that A(1,2)=A(2,4)=A(4,6)=A(6,8)=A(8,10)=1 other elements 0.

please help

Answer (score 7):

You could use the constructor for sparse matrices:

```
full(sparse(r,c,1))
```

by the way, if you want to apply this to large matrices with many zeros, stay with the sparse one. It uses much less memory for matrices with many zeros:

```
sparse(r,c,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.de/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to accomplish this.

First, construct a matrix made out of zeros:

```
A = zeros(max(r),max(c));
```

Then set the elements to `1`:

```
A( size(A,1) * (c-1) + r ) = 1;
```

Comment: I believe the second `10` can be replaced by `size(A,1)` to make this one more generic.

Comment: I think both `10`s should be replaced by `max(r)`, well actually the first should preallocate as Luis Mendo does. Good solution though!

Answer (score 2):

First preallocate `A` to a zero matrix of appropriate size (given by the maximum values in `r` and `c`). Then, to address the desired entries, you need to convert to [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html), which you can do easily with [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
A = zeros(max(r),max(c));
A(sub2ind(size(A),r,c)) = 1;
```